# angular.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, service, mongoose

I'm trying to insert a details page of each of my captures using my service.

Though when I try loading the page with an id in my service (example: `/capture/5740c1eae324ae1f19b7fc30`) I get undefined, using this code:

```
app.factory('captureApi', ['$http', function($http){

var urlBase = 'URL';
// ==> Gives back an array as such:
//[
//{
//  "_id": "5740c1e3e324ae1f19b7fc2f",
//  "created_at": "2016-05-21T20:15:38.554Z",
//  "userId": "118000609287736585411",
//  "place": "place",
// "birdname": "birdname",
//  "__v": 0
//},
//{
//  "_id": "5740c1eae324ae1f19b7fc30",
//  "created_at": "2016-05-21T20:15:38.554Z",
//  "userId": "118000609287736585411",
//  "place": "place",
//  "birdname": "birdname",
//  "__v": 0
//},
//{ 
//  ...
//}
//]

return {
    getAllCaptures : function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    },

    insertCapture : function(data) {
        return $http.post(urlBase, data);
    },

    findCapture : function(id) {
        //both give undefined
        console.log(_.find(urlBase, function(capture){return capture._id == id}));
        console.log(_.find(urlBase, function(capture){return capture.id == id}));
        return _.find(urlBase, function(capture){return capture.id == id});
    }
    }
}]);
```

On the server side I am using mongoose/mongodb:

**-route:**

```
var Capture = require('../models/capture');
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/captures', function(req, res){
        var capture = new Capture();
        capture.birdname = req.body.birdname;
        capture.place =  req.body.place;
        capture.userId = req.body.userId;
        capture.author = req.body.author;
        capture.picture = req.body.picture;
        capture.created_at = new Date();

        capture.save(function(err, data){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            console.log(req.body);
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.get('/captures', function(req, res){
        Capture.find({}, function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

     router.delete('/captures', function(req, res){
          Capture.remove({}, function(err){
              res.json({result: err ? 'error' : 'ok'});
          });
      });

    router.get('/captures/:id', function(req, res){
         Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data){
             res.json(data);
         });
     });

     router.delete('/captures/:id', function(req, res){
         Capture.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
             res.json({result: err ? 'error' : 'ok'});
         });
     });

    // router.post('/captures/:id', function(req, res){
    //     Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data){
    //         var capture = data;
    //         capture.birdname = req.body.birdname;
    //         capture.place.city = req.body.place.city;
    //         capture.place.country = req.body.place.country;

    //         capture.save(function(err, data){
    //             if(err)
    //                 throw err;
    //             res.json(data);
    //         });
    //     })
    // })
}
```

**-model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var captureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    birdname: {type: String, required: true},
    place: {type: String, required: true},
    userId: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: String, required: true},
    picture: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    created_at: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Capture', captureSchema)
```

Here is my server.js (extra info):

```
// Init Express Web Framework
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// Set view engine to EJS & set views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));

// Database Connection
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./server/config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));               
app.use(bodyParser.text());                                    
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json'}));  

// Main route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

// // catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//     var err = new Error('Not Found');
//     err.status = 404;
//     next(err);
// });

// API 
var api = express.Router();
require('./server/routes/capture')(api);
app.use('/api', api);

// Set routes to other pages
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

// Port Settings
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP);
console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
```

---

On the client side I have the following the trigger the page:

```
 $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl',
        data: {
            requiresLogin: false
        },
        resolve: {
          $title: function() { return 'Home'; }
        }
    })

    .state('dash', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'dashCtrl',
        data: {
            requiresLogin: true
        },
        resolve: {
          $title: function() { return 'Dashboard'; }
        }
    })

    .state('capture', {
      url: '/capture',
      templateUrl: 'partials/capture.html',
      controller: 'captureCtrl',
        data: {
            requiresLogin: true
        },
        resolve: {
          $title: function() { return 'Capture'; }
        }
    })

    .state('viewCapture', {
      url: '/capture/:id',
      templateUrl: 'partials/viewCapture.html',
      controller: 'viewCaptureCtrl',
      data: {
            requiresLogin: true
        },
      resolve: {
        $title: function() { return 'Capture Detail'; }        
      }
    })
```

viewCaptureCtrl.js:

```
app.controller('viewCaptureCtrl', ['$scope', 'captureApi', '$stateParams', '$http', function($scope, captureApi, $stateParams, $http) {

     var id = $stateParams.id;

      $scope.viewCapture = function() {
        captureApi.findCapture(id)
            .then(function(data) {
              $scope.capture = data;
            });
      };

      $scope.viewCapture();

}]);
```

Anyone have an idea why my find function is giving an undefined?
Help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `findCapture(id)` is returning a promise?

Comment: it's undefined. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my service, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reference `underscoreJS` and inject it into your service. Document:  http://app-genesis.com/underscorejswithangularjs/

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory('_', function() { return window._; });

//inject into capture api factory
app.factory('captureApi', ['$http', '_', function($http, _){
    //do stuff with _
}]);
```

**Edit:**  But I'm not familiar with `_.find()`; if it returns a promise or not.  If not, you'll need to make use of `$q` to create a promise and return it in order to use `then()`.

```
//inject into capture api factory
app.factory('captureApi', ['$http', '_', '$q',
    function($http, _, $q) {
        return {
            findCapture: function(id) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                try {
                    var results = _.find(); //do stuff with _
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                } catch (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                }

                //you need to return a promise in order to use then()
                return deferred.promise;

            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: The output still gives `undefined` but a thanks for already something that would probably need fixing in the future..

Comment: @CedricBongaerts I don't think `_.find()` returns a promise.  You'll need to make use of `$q`.  See edit.

Comment: You're code gives `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: , $qProvider <- , $q <- captureApi`

Comment: I don't know then.  Here's documentation on $q if you need more help.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I made a mistake, it was correct, wrote it down wrong I'm guessing.
Anyways it gives back a promise now, but the value is undefined. `Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state
:
Object
status
:
1
value
:
undefined
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object`